# Slice/Cut/Divide an artwork and paste them in different artboards (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, grids, artboard, slices

I have an vector Logo file. I need to increase its size to 10m x 10m. Printer can only take upto  1.3m x 2.5m , so he asked me to slice/cut/divide/tile(I dunno the exact word for it) the entire file into small boxes of 1m x 2m. Therefore total 50 files. He will print all those 50 files and paste it together to make the logo.
Can anyone please tell me how to slice/cut/divide/tile the entire artwork into small box and paste them in different,here 50, artboards? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When printing from Illustrator, you don't need to do that. Just select "Tile Full Pages" in scaling and Illustrator will do that for you:

[image]

If you can't print from Illustrator, try printing to postscript file or PDF.

Comment: Thank you Lukigi for your reply. The problem is, i cant print directly from illustrator. There is a ripping software for that.
Btw how to increase the size to 10m x 10m, i guess maximum artboard size is around ~600 cm right?